# Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Setup failed

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, installation

I have windows 8.1 pro 4 GB RAM.

Visual studio installation setup shows error:

Microsoft .net framework 4.6
the extended attributes are inconsistent

I chose custom installation and only selected **"Microsoft Web Developer Tools"**.

I have a brand new laptop and no other software is installed. 
Ay ideas how to solve this error and install visual studio 2015 in my machine?

Thanks very much

Comment: look in the logs in temp folder what in detail fails. Otherwise we can't help

Comment: have you looked into the logs? Which error do you see there?

Comment: Does your issue is solved or not? If not, to find the detail error information of this failed installation, you can use http://aka.ms/vscollect to gather the installation logs. After using it, you will find vslogs.zip under %temp% folder then upload the file to https://onedrive.live.com/ and share the link here. I found someone met the error “the extended attributes are inconsistent” with other operations, changed the Sound Scheme by right clicking on the desktop, select ‘Personalize’–Themes-Advanced sound settings and change Sound Scheme to ‘Windows Default’, then this error was solved.

Comment: Yes. My issue has solved. I first installed .Net framework 4.6 Then ran the setup for visual studio 2015, unchecked update 3, after that it installed successfully

Comment: @Software2k14, since your issue is solved by yourself, you can add a reply with your solution and mark it as answer, that can help other community members who meet the same issue like yours to easier search this helpful solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First download and install .Net Framework 4.6. Then

1. Run Visual studio setup
2. Choose custom installation
3. Uncheck update 3
4. Click install.